# Failure adding graph to remote SPARQL store

Tags: sparql, rdflib

I am trying to add triples to a remote SPARQL repository, using Python and rdflib 4.2.2.

Adding statement-wise works:

```
gsu = rdflib.plugins.stores.sparqlstore.SPARQLUpdateStore(sparql_endpoint, update_endpoint, bNodeAsURI=False, sparql11=True, context_aware=False)
for stmt in subGraph: 
    gsu.add( stmt )
```

But I think it would be more efficient to add graph-wise, i.e

```
remoteGraph = rdflib.Graph(gsu)
remoteGraph.add( subGraph )
```

Unfortunatley this resutls in the error: ValueError: too many values to unpack

Did someone have success in adding a graph to a remote repo?

Comment: According to the docs `add` expects a single triple. Instead, you can do `G1 += G2` to add a graph `G2` to the graph `G1`.

Comment: @Joakim, comments to [this issue](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/issues/298) contains some approaches and code snippets.